# Is it possible to open a download ebook file via iBook?

Tags: iphone, ios, epub, ibooks

I got a question, which is, what if I can download a ebook file, eg .epub or PDF, then I list this file on a `tableview`, now I select one of the books.

Can I open via iBook?

Or I need to implement a reader to open the file?

Also got another question , I download a pdf file in my folder

The path I log it out , looks right

Here is the code:

```
 NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *ePubSubFolder = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Books"];
 NSString *pdfPath = [ePubSubFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.pdfFileName]];    
 CFURLRef pdfURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL,(CFStringRef)pdfPath, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, FALSE);
 NSLog(@"PDF URL: %@", pdfURL);
 pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
 CFRelease(pdfURL);
```

The log result is

```
../iPhone%20Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/06BA5929-3531-4AC3-B524-6CC74DC7E2C9/Documents/Books/Repeat%20After%20Me%20User's%20Guide.pdf
```

Do I did something wrong ?I won't show any thing on my view.

Many thanks for all reply or answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in IOS when you open a pdf using any application you get an option on the top right corner  click on it and you can see options like open in ibooks etc.. I have tried this with many apps.

this is what I do to use some pdf on my ios devices.. load the file into a dropbox folder on the comp open it in the device in dropbox and then move it over to ibooks..

Comment: Thanks ! But do you have any sample code to show how to show the options to open file ?
I really have no idea ...